# Non-algebraic K3 surfaces in characteristic $p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces, positive-characteristic

I have a very naive question.

Recall that over the field of complex numbers, there exist non-algebraic K3 surfaces. Namely, smooth non-projective simply connected compact complex surfaces with trivial canonical bundle. Such surfaces often come in useful when studying the moduli and deformations of K3 surfaces over $\mathbb{C}$.

> Is there a notion of "non-algebraic" K3 surfaces over fields of positive characteristic?

As I say above, I am well aware that this question is very naive. Possible guesses I had in mind were formal schemes / stacks / rigid analytic spaces / ...?

Comment: For every uncountable, algebraically closed field $k$, I believe there exist formally smooth, formal schemes over $\text{Spf}\ k[[t]]$ with closed fibers being K3 surfaces and that are not algebraizable.  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Quite possibly; does every non-algebraic K3 surface over $\mathbb{C}$ arise this way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let me briefly expand on Jason's comment.

Actually, "formal scheme" is the right word here.

For any K3 surface $X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of any characteristic one has $$h^0(X, T_X)=0, \quad  h^1(X, T_X)=20, \quad \, h^2(X, T_X)=0,$$
so the functor of Artin rings $$F \colon  (\textbf{Art}) \to (\textbf{Sets})$$  describing the first-order deformations of $X$ is pro-representable and unobstructed, hence it is represented by a complete, regular local ring $A$ of dimension $20$. More precisely, $$A \cong  k[[x_1, \ldots, x_{20}]],$$
where $x_1, \ldots, x_{20}$ are indeterminates.

Thus there is a formal universal deformation $\widehat{\mathcal{X}} \to \textrm{Specf} (A)$ of $X$; however, such a deformation *is not effective*, in the sense that *there exists no algebraic deformation* $\mathcal{X} \to \textrm{Spec}(A)$, where $ \mathcal X$ is a scheme, such that $\widehat{\mathcal{X}}$ is the formal completion of $\mathcal{X}$ along the closed fibre $X$. In fact, a straightforward cup product computation shows that any algebraic family of K3 surfaces with injective Kodaira-Spencer map at any point has dimension $\leq 19$.

Deligne showed that any K3 surface over $k$ can be lifted to $\mathbb{C}$. So there is an analogy with the complex analytic theory, where the deformation space, as a complex manifold, has dimension $20$, but the algebraic K3 surfaces form a (countable union of) $19$-dimensional subfamilies.

More details on this topic can be found in the books *Deformations of algebraic schemes* (Sernesi) and *Deformation theory* (Hartshorne).

Comment: To add a useful comment for beginners: The big difference between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$ here is that we can talk about convergence of power series over $\mathbb{C}$. Thus, we can take the formal power series in the $x_i$ and plug in nonzero complex numbers to get non-algebraic $K_3$'s. Over $\mathbb{F}_p$, the power series still exist, but it doesn't make sense to evaluate them anywhere except at $0$.

Comment: Right, good point.

Comment: since the word "beginner" has been used, a link to a previous answer seems relevant (I didn't know beforehand that all complete regular local rings are pretty much all created equal) http://mathoverflow.net/a/191737/73972