# Intuition behind RDP (Rational Double Points)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities, k3-surfaces

Let $S$ be a surface (so a $2$-dimensional proper $k$-scheme) and $s$ a singular point which is a ***rational double point***.

One common characterisation of a RDP is that under sufficient conditions there exist a resultion morphsim $r: \tilde{S}\to S$ of surfaces such that the fiber $r^{-1}(s)$ is an set consisting of rational
curves with self-intersection-number $−2$. This leads to classification of such RDP's via Dynkin-diagrams for ADE-curves.

I'm keen interested in geometrical intuition behind the RDP's. Concretely, my question is if there exist characterisation for a rational double point on the level of it's stalk $\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$ which "reflects" in some way the geometry of this rational double point?

Namely, since $S$ is proper and therefore finitely generated $k$-algebra, can the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$ (or maybe at least it's completion or base change to algebraically closed field) obtain the shape like $k[x,y,z]_s/(f)$ where $f$ represents the curve/geometry of this singularity? If yes, what kind of polynomial $f$ might be?

Why it is called a ***double*** point? Does this mean that $f$ is contained in in the square $m_s^2$ of the unique maximal ideal $m_s$ but not in $m_s^3$?

Or is it a too naive approach in order to understand intuitively the "nature" of RDP's?

Comment: The completion is indeed a hypersurface and they can be written down explicitly. For example, the $A_n$ singularities have equations $z^{n+1}=xy$. Similar equations exist for $D_n$s and the $E$ s.

Comment: @Mohan:so the "geometry" and meaning of "double" indeed only crystallize out after completion? following point: which conditions should $S$ fullfil to garantee that the completions of stalks $O_{S,s}^{\wedge} $ are from the shape $k[[x,y,z]]/(f)$?

Comment: More concretely in light of this thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191725/completion-of-a-local-ring-of-a-curve

I'm looking for conditions for $S$ such that $O_{S,s}^{\wedge}= k[[x,y,z]]/(f)$ where if $s$ is regular then $f$ is linear and therefore wlog $O_{S,s}^{\wedge}= k[[x,y,z]]/(f) \cong k[[x,y]]$. Otherwise $f \in m_s ^2 \backslash m_s^3$.

Comment: The main obstructions which I encounter here are that I didn't assume that $k$ is alg closed nor that $S$ is projective (only proper). So the criterions presented in the liked thread from my comment above don't work. Is there nevertheless an argument which garantee that the stalk completions in this situation have this "nice" shape?

Comment: I would suggest that you look at the classic paper of M. Artin on rational singularities.

Comment: I would also recommend *Fifteen characterizations of rational double points and simple critical points*, by Alan Durfee (L'enseignement Math. 25 (1979) 131-163).