# Structure of Complete Local Rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings, complete-intersection

Let $X$ be a proper $n$-dimensional $k$-scheme and $x \in X$ a closed point. Consider the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. We consider now it's completion $O_{X,x}^{\wedge}$ wrt it's maximal ideal $m_x$.

My QUESTIONS concerns the analysis of the structure of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$:

When $O_{X,x}^{\wedge}$ has the shape $ k[[x_1,x_2,..., x_m]]/I$?

When - more specifically - it has the shape $ k[[x_1,x_2,..., x_{n+1}]]/(f)$ for $f \in  k[[x_1,x_2,..., x_{n+1}]]$ non zero divisor?

Are there any reconmendable reference with thread the structure of such local complete rings rigoriously?

My CONSIDERATIONS /starting point:

The main tool to treat this problem is of course the Cohen strucure theorem. It provides especially that $$O_{X,x}^{\wedge} \cong \Lambda [[x_1, \ldots , x_ n]]/I$$ where $\Lambda$ is the "mysterious" Cohen ring.

Which criterions are neccessary & sufficient to settle that here $\Lambda=k$ (references?)?

Another point is under which conditions we obtain a more "concretely" form $$ O_{X,x}^{\wedge}= k[[x_1,x_2,..., x_{n+1}]]/(f)$$

?

This question arises from following former thread of mine: [Intuition behind RDP (Rational Double Points)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331251/intuition-behind-rdp-rational-double-points?noredirect=1#comment826002_331251)

Comment: The residue field of $\mathcal{O}_{X, x}$ is $k(x)$, while the residue field of $k[[x_1, \ldots, x_n]]/I$ is $k$. So a necessary (and in fact sufficient) condition is that $x\in X(k)$.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger: Do you have a recommandable reference / sketch of the proof for the "sufficient" part?

Comment: Pick generators $t_1, \ldots, t_n \in \mathfrak{m}_x$. The induced homomorphism $k[[T_1, \ldots, T_n]] \to \mathfrak{O}^\wedge_{X, x}$ sending $T_i$ to $t_i$ is then easily seen to be surjective.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger: so $O_{X,x}^{\wedge}= k(x)[[x_1,x_2,..., x_{n+1}]]/I$ holds always when the maximal ideal is finitely generated? Are there any conditions on $X$ which garantee that the completions have moreover the shape $O_{X,x}^{\wedge}= k[[x_1,x_2,..., x_{n+1}]]/(f)$?

Comment: The condition is $\ \dim \mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2\leq n+1$.

Comment: @abx: In the case $n=2$ I understand the argument: Assume for example that $I=(f,g)$ and $k[[x_1,x_2,x_3]]/I=  O_{X,x}$. $O_{X,x}$ has dimension two and every minimal prime in $k[[x_1,x_2,x_3]]$ containing $I$ corresponds to a minimal prime in $O_{X,x}$ (and is therefore not maximal) so $I$ has height $1$ and is therefore principal in $k[[x_1,x_2,x_3]]$. But for higher $n$ this argument seems to fail because then not every minimal prime containing $I$ has automatically height $1$. Can the argument nevertheless be rescued to deduce that $I$ is principal aslo for $n \ge 3$?

Comment: OK, I was assuming that your scheme is irreducible at $x$ — otherwise anything can happen.